# Search template pages

Tags: ee2, templates, search

I created an ExpressionEngine site.  The site has various channels with entry data (ie. news, blog posts).  I added exp:search:simple_form and it works great for the channel entries.

However, I also have a number of template pages with static content.  The content is so different on each page, that I don't believe it makes sense to create a single "About Us" template and create an About Us channel with entries for annual report, history, leadership, and the index. I need to be able to search "static" content on my template pages as well as the regular channel entries.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jvyqbgy5lf4ux4g/Template_Manager.png

Does anyone know of a "good" way to search all template pages within an ExpressionEngine site? Should I consider some other "non-EE" method of site search?

Comment: Why not to create an channel for all of this, called `pages`, for example, and to use the [Pages Module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/pages/index.html) to [set the template](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/pages/control_panel/index.html#default-template-channel-name) to each one?

Comment: @RobsonSobral how would I format the actual page? My templates basically have HTML inside of an exp:partials tag:

{exp:partials:set name="body_content"}
  <div class="body-content">
    <h1 class="title">Our History</h1>
    <p>The establishment of The...

I have lists, Bootstrap modals, wells, tables, and other varying types of content.

Comment: why this content needs to be static? Why not a channel with `title`, `body` and a grid field called `sections`, wit `subtitles` and `section`? This can be enough for a lot o different pages. You can even create tables with markdown.

If this can't help you, I gonna post to you use Google Search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't going to manage the content with EE, you won't be able to search the content with EE.

Either move your content to channels as suggested (I've had sites with channels with two fields - title and page content, the latter holding whatever HTML is necessary), or implement a Google Custom Search that will search your rendered pages.

Low has a nice add-on to help with EE-templating the Google results:

http://gotolow.com/addons/low-googlesearch

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I actually switched over to [Google CSE](https://www.google.com/cse/), the free branded version for now. I will look into LOW, but I've already integrated gCSE into my site with a few style overrides.